# Visual Studio Missing "Open in blend" option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, expression-blend-3

Am I missing something or does that "Open in blend" option in Visual Studio 2008 not exist anymore?

I am using VS 2008 SP1 + Expression Studio 3.0.

I can do it the other way around, from blend to visual studio, but not visual studio to blend.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the "Open in Expression Blend" is only available in Silverlight projects, for WPF projects the option does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had the trial version of blend, uninstalled and then installed Expression Studio (from my MSDN subscription). The option in Silverlight projects was gone.

I found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/anandt/archive/2008/03/05/open-in-expression-blend.aspx) that all I needed to do was to add the following registry entry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\VS\BlendLaunchPath

And this should point to the full path where expession blend is (in my case: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\Blend.exe)

After this all I needed to do was to restart Visual Studio and there it was again!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me under Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, and Expression Blend .NET 4 Trial

Comment: VS 2010 and Blend 4 Trial - Registry entry is already there, but no joy.